# What is the difference between select from function and select function

Tags: postgresql, select, execution-plan, explain

I am doing a test with [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-srf.html) function on Postgres **v.9.6** on Ubuntu 16.04. So, I get a curiosity about loops (***loops=100000***) when calling that function as below.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM t5
  WHERE id in (SELECT a FROM generate_series(1,10));
Aggregate  (cost=627262.00..627262.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=60.534..60.534 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on t5  (cost=0.00..627137.00 rows=50000 width=0) (actual time=0.048..50.267 rows=100000 loops=1)
        Filter: (SubPlan 1)
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=100000)
Planning time: 0.161 ms
Execution time: 60.599 ms
```

**However**, If I change the query. The loop and result will change.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM t5
  WHERE id in (SELECT generate_series(1,10) a);
Aggregate  (cost=1488.51..1488.52 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.050..0.050 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=17.80..1363.51 rows=50000 width=0) (actual time=0.025..0.046 rows=10 loops=1)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=17.51..19.51 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=10 loops=1)
              Group Key: generate_series(1, 10)
              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.007 rows=10 loops=1)
        ->  Index Only Scan using t5_pkey on t5  (cost=0.29..6.71 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=10)
              Index Cond: (id = (generate_series(1, 10)))
              Heap Fetches: 10
Planning time: 0.124 ms
Execution time: 0.086 ms
```

Here's script to create table

```
CREATE TABLE t5 ( id serial primary key, a int, b text);
INSERT INTO t5 (a,b) SELECT a, 'test_' || a FROM generate_series(1, 100000) a;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not the `FROM` that's causing the different query plans. It's the bad aliasing.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM t5
  WHERE id in (SELECT generate_series(1,10));
```

And

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM t5
  WHERE id in (SELECT generate_series FROM generate_series(1,10));
```

will return the same plan. As will this,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM t5
  WHERE id in (SELECT x FROM generate_series(1,10) AS gs(x));
```

However, this won't.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM t5
  WHERE id in (SELECT a FROM generate_series(1,10));
```

**Notice: you forget to alias the generate_series to `a`** Now you're essentially running a correlated subquery. It's not just more work, but it's returning the entire table and not just 10 rows.

Comment: Thanks Evan. Running `SELECT a FROM generate_series(1,10)` query will error `column "a" does not exist`; but with query above it doesn't raise any errors. Could you please explain it to me ?

Comment: It won't return all the rows of the table but possibly a big number of them. And uses a different plan because it has to scan the whole table to check all rows and each `id` vs each `a` value. The condition `WHERE id in (SELECT a FROM generate_series(1,10))` is equivalent to `WHERE id in (SELECT a UNION ALL SELECT a UNION ALL ... (10 times) ... UNION ALL SELECT a)` or just `WHERE id = a`. It doesn't error because you have a column `a` in table `t5`.

Comment: Thanks @ypercubeᵀᴹ . `a` will be called `10 times` of each record (I think).

Comment: I don't know what you mean with *"`a` will be called"*. `a` is a column in your query (version 1) and I was referring to that.

Comment: i.e. for each `t5` rows,  `a` will be duplicated 10 times in `select a from generate_series(1,10)` .